# why is pyplot and seaborn histplot not showing anything?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

i have a dataset with a column for 'revenue' and i sample 1000 averages, then i just use plt.hist() to show the distribution obtained, but the plot is empty, altho the x-axis seems to be in the right range... I also added a axvline() for the original data mean. this line is showing but not the sampled data, please let me know, i use to do it normally but i must be forgetting something. here's the code:

```
`sns.set()
 ini_sample = np.empty(500)
 for i in range(500):
     ini_sample[i] = ini_data['revenue'].sample(frac=1).mean()
 plt.hist(ini_sample)
 plt.axvline(x=ini_data['revenue'].mean())
 plt.show()`
```

can't post img, but the histogram is empty, with the y axis [0,50,100,150,200,250,300,350] and the x axis [0,84,86,88,90,92]... all is actually plotted is the vertical line around 87.

Comment: Instead of `.sample(frac=1)` which always returns the complete dataset, you could do `.sample(frac=1, replace=True)` which allows duplicates. This would prevent always getting exactly the same mean.  Did you look into `print(ini_sample)` and noticed the values?

Comment: See [bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) on Wikipedia why replacements are needed.

Comment: it was replace=True thanks...i can see why it didn't work as False

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `sample(frac=1)` just returns all data in each iteration instead of sampling from it. If you want 1% of your data as samples, use `frac=0.01`.

Comment: it was because of replace = False... had to be True. thanks tho